# Android setting Button width half the screen

Tags: android, xml, layout

How to setup(in XML) that the button will have width half of screen. I found only wrap content, match parent(fills whole screen) and exact amount of dp eg: 50dp.
How to set it exactly hold the screen?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:weightSum="2"
>

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/buttonCollect"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:paddingLeft="8dp"
     android:paddingRight="8dp"
     android:text="przycisk" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can be done by having two widgets on your layout: 
use a LinearLayout and set `layout_width="fill_parent"` on both widgets (Button and another widget ), and set layout_weight also to the same value .
and the LinearLayout will split the width between the two widget equally and your button will occupy half of the screen.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal">

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/buttonCollect"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:paddingLeft="8dp"
     android:paddingRight="8dp"
     android:text="przycisk" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: Great. Simple and clever. Thank you!

Comment: Nicest solutcion for xml!

Answer (score 8):

This is not possible in XML. However, you can do it in Java by getting the width of the display using [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html), dividing it by 2 and setting it as the width of the button. Something like this:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
int buttonWidth = width/2;
//Apply this to your button using the LayoutParams for whichever layout you have.
```

Comment: Thank you. That's sth I will need little bit later.

Answer (score 0):

Use a textview.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewHelper"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Then add the two buttons, or just one of them, to left and/or right of it.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/saveList"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/deleteAllPlaylists"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewHelper"
    android:text="@string/save_temp_playlist" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/deleteAllPlaylists"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textViewHelper"    
    android:text="@string/delete_all_playlists" />
```

answer was found [here](http://sdroid.blogspot.gr/2011/01/relativelayout-alignment-trick.html)

My first post on stack, hope i helped XD