# android simple layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I want make 2 button take half of the screen width, but what ever i tru only one button came in screen and take full screenwidth. I wanted it for all resolution so dont want to make fix width. one button will take left half and other will take right half how it can do

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:gravity="center">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_gravity="left" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" 
            android:layout_gravity="right" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This question has been asked a few times on stackoverflow - one example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286147/android-setting-button-width-half-the-screen/11286169#11286169 - if you use the search you will find many more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following layout technique. Use `Linear Layout`. Assign `layout_width` of your buttons to `0dip`. Assign `layout_weight`as `1` to each button, so that they occupy **equal of the total width**. Assign `layout_height` of each button as `match_parent`

```
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ButtonLeft"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="ButtonLeft"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ButtonRight"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="ButtonRight"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**PS:** If you want them to occupy half screen height instead of width, change `orientation` of layout to `vertical` and interchange values between `layout_width` and `layout_height` in above XML.

**About layout_weight**

`layout_weight` decides how the parent element space is divided between it's children. If you want 1:4 division of your width between your buttons, then you assign `layout_weight` of 1 button to "1" and the other button to "3" --> 1/(1+3) = 1/4 as you wanted. Again what space does `layout_weight` work on - height or width?. `layout_weight` does the distribution from the free or unused space. In the above layout, we assigned `0dip` to the widths of the buttons. So the horizontal space or width of the parent is unused or free and that is divided between your buttons depending on `layout_weight`. Hope this helps.

Comment: perfect it solved the problem, but i cant understand the layout weight property, can u give me useful guide on this?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include the concept of `layout_weight`

Answer (score 3):

You can define `layout_weight` to define the size of a view. Using `layout_width` to be `0dp` is the best way if used with weight settings (according to lint). When both buttons have the same value, both are using 50% width. Play around with the values to get a feeling for that.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" 
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: perfect it solved the problem, but i cant understand the layout weight property, can u give me useful guide on this?

Comment: There are a lot of [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean) and answers. Just use the search.